# How can I use JavaScript to print non-visible code?

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the following script to echo visible text on the screen...

```
<h1 id="MyText"></h1>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('MyText');
{ if (italian || french || german)
{ el.innerHTML = (
(italian && 'ciao') ||
(french && 'salut') ||
(german && 'hallo') ); }
else { el.innerHTML = 'hello';}
}
</script>
```

How should I edit this script, to make it work in case I want it to type a non visible word in the html?

Example:

- In CSS I have:

```
#ciao{height:350px;}
#salut{height:10px;}
#hallo{height:3000px;}
```

- In my code I want to define my table height basing on these conditions:

```
<div id="MyText">
```

The problem is with the above code, this will result in printing a visible text, instead of rather choosing the css id. So how am I supposed to edit the script?

Comment: for example like this: `el.setAttribute('id', 'ciao');`

Comment: @Kazz can you be more specific? (sorry, newbie here)

Comment: @D. Dragon you can set MyText's id to ciao/salut/hallo

Comment: Tried the following, but isn't working: <script>
var el = document.getElementById('MyText');
{ if (italian || french || german)
{ el.setAttribute = ('id', 
(italian && 'ciao') ||
(french && 'salut') ||
(german && 'hallo') ); }
else { el.setAttribute('id', 'hello');}
}
</script><div id="MyText">

Comment: I think you might be thinking of the `class` tag? Keep your id "MyText" and add/remove classes.

Answer (score 2):

It is more idiomatic to add an appropriate class to the div element. [edit] it appears as though you are looking to set the class based on the contents of the div. This is generally a difficult thing to do but here is one approach. Another would be to set a property of the div and then do a `:before` hack to create a pseudo element with the text of the property.

```js
const langauges = {
  "ciao":"italian",
  "salut":"french",
  "hallo":"german",
  "hello":"english"
}

const updateClass = (el)=>{
  if(langauges[el.innerHTML] != undefined){

    el.className = langauges[el.innerHTML];
  }
}

const onChange = (event)=>{
  const el = event.target;
  updateClass(el);
}

var el = document.getElementById('MyText');
el.addEventListener("input",onChange,false);
updateClass(el);
```

```css
.italian{height:350px; color:blue;}
.french{height:10px; color:red;}
.german{height:3000px; color:yellow;}
.english{height:3000px; color:purple;}
```

```html
<h1 id="MyText" contenteditable="true">ciao</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is again about "visible" text printed. Ciao, hello or whatever word is displayed. You added a dimension and colour. How to make this same thing work with div id="ciao/hello/salut"? Using this method will keep div id="MyText" exactly as MyText, not turning into salut/ciao/hello

Comment: To make it simpler to understand (even it's stupid condition, but just as example) how to make it work with div align="MyText" if Italian=center; french=left; else=justify?

Comment: You cant define your own align attribute values. Those are built into HTML. You can, however, use classes to style your text however you wish. `<div class="italian"></div><style>.italian{text-align: center;}</style>`

Comment: You can then use `.classList` to manipulate the classes using javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: I took another stab at what you may be going for, but I think you need to clarify your problem in your question.